# post payment callbacks issue on barclaycard forms

Tags: payment-gateway, payment-processing

My website can successfully accept the payments from Barclaycard.
But it does not return back to the main website.

```
private $_url = 'https://payments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/prod/orderstandard.asp';
private $_testurl = 'https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp';
```

What combination of domain name and folder name (prod|test) has to be used?
Or, any special configurations necessary to fix?

The after the payment is successful, the gateway has to redirect the customer to my website.
It currently halts on their page with the message:

```
An error occured when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please set this form field in your payment form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ACCEPTURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="DECLINEURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="EXCEPTIONURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="">
```